# Are the electron and positron doublets in any mathematical sense?

Tags: symmetry, antimatter, leptons

I know left handed electrons and electron neutrinos are isospin doublets. Is there any analogous way in which an electron and a positron are related? My first thought is some sort time-parity doublet.

Comment: In a Dirac spinor, two of the four components describe the particle and the other two describe the antiparticle.

Comment: Yes, you can look at the outer automorphisms of the Lorentz group, they are "doublets" under CPT. One does *not* need Dirac spinors for that, already a Weyl fermion transforms under these transformations. Since this is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$, not many would call this a "doublet", though.